# Sql server temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a temp table who contains the number of employes of each department. If the department have no employer, we need to print a message.

```
IF (count(*) = 0) 
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'Espace vide'
    END
    else 
    Select deptno,count(*)  
    from emp    
    group by deptno;
```

this is the query to see how many employes are in each dept, but I don't know how to create a temp table with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choose suitable for you method:

```
Select deptno,count(*) cnt
INTO #TempTable  
from emp    
group by deptno;

select 
  *,
  CASE cnt WHEN 0 THEN 'Espace vide' ELSE NULL END AS column1
FROM #TempTable

if exists(SELECT * FROM #TempTable WHERE cnt = 0) PRINT 'Espace vide'
```